# Pandas expand rows by yearly group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question as to how to expand a data frame by grouping. I have two columns "convocation" and "year". I need to expand the rows by the years within the convocation. I already have some of the data completed, so I need to do this by the group with NAs. The years also do not follow a pattern.

The data looks like this:

```
Conv   Year
1      .
2      1991 
2      1992
2      1993
2      1994
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
Conv   Year
1      1985
1      1986
1      1987
2      1991 
2      1992
2      1993
2      1994
```

Comment: `date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1980', end='1/12/1994', freq='y')`

Comment: Hi, why are the new values 1985 to 1987? Why three of them and not four, like for Conv==2?